# What is the best way to fetch multiple stores (from server) at once, instead fetching them one by one?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have multiple stores like categories, units, currencies. In my project after a successful login I fetch them one by one.

```
store.getters['category/isReady'] || store.dispatch('category/fetchCategories');
store.getters['currency/isReady'] || store.dispatch('currency/fetchCurrencies');
store.getters['unit/isReady'] || store.dispatch('unit/fetchUnits');
```

So for each I make a axios request, get the data and store it. But instead I want to make one request and get all of them and then store them at once.

PS: By the way I use namespaced modules for each store I have mentioned.

Comment: Make an `INIT` action that fetches/stores all necessary data at once, and dispatch the action at startup.

Comment: That sounds like a good way to go @tony19 . You mean creating an additional store with a INIT action and call it once. But how can I acces other stores within this initializer store?

Comment: No, not an additional store. Put the action in the same store that holds your state.

Comment: If you want this done with a single request it would be a case of how you query your database on the backend

Comment: @Daniel_Knights I created a response where all queries are made at once and returned to the client. no problem on the server side.

Comment: So then you only need to make one Axios request on login. Or am I missing the issue?

Comment: Well it cant be called directly as an issue @Daniel_Knights . I want somehow to optimize the vuex. So instead making multiple request for each store (I have about 6 may increase) I want to return them all in one request and store them at once instead making each stores dispatch and axios call. Right now I prepared a request where brings all data together and returns (in a single response) to the client. But I need to put each data into its own store.

Comment: You could just use the same mutations you would have used for multiple requests from that single action couldn't you?

Comment: @tony19 I am sorry for bugging but I didn't understand your suggestion quite well. Do you mean to get the collected response and store for each specific store using rootState ?

Comment: @Daniel_Knights the stores are separated store modules like unit module, unit, route and so on. Each module has its own actions which fetch its data. My difficulty is to store the mixed response data to each of these separate modules in one place.

Comment: You could create separate actions in each module which only sets the state, and call `dispatch` on each one from the single request

Comment: I think we have a miscommunication in semantics. By "store", I mean a Vuex store, and there is usually only one store per app. I think you mean "module" when you say "store" (as in you have multiple modules in your store that each have their own state). For instance, each of the getters in your question refer to a state of a specific module within the store. I would create the `INIT` action in the root module (the store itself) that fetches the necessary data, then **dispatch** the response to the individual modules (or commit a module **mutation**s) as needed.

Comment: @tony19 the miscommunication was my fault. I used the wrong names and had a little lack of knowledge of vuex. Actually I didn't know that the root module could be used still like a store (with actions and other stuff) when module system was used. Thanks to you I learned it. And I wrote it as you told.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @tony19 and @Daniel_Knights I now use a single request to set all my initial data from server side. After I receive the server response I store them for each module.

So within my store root (store/index.js)

```
modules: ...
actions: {
    initialize(ctx){
        axios.get(process.env.API_URL + "provide/initials")
            .then((response) => {
                ctx.dispatch('category/setFlat', response.data.flat);
                ctx.dispatch('category/setNest', response.data.nest);
                ctx.dispatch('currency/set', response.data.currencies);
                ctx.dispatch('unit/set', response.data.units);
                ...
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                return { status: 'error', message: 'Problem occurred.', orinigal: e };
            });
        }
    },
...
```

While I before dispatched each module, now I just dispatch the root module `store.dispatch('initialize');`  and thats it